# Iron Python get attributes of class instance, based on string input

Tags: python, ironpython, instances

This is my code, I'm new to python and can't understand why this wont work, I want to be able to print the class instances attributes after that particular instance has been selected by the user. I'm not sure if this is even possible but if it is some help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, happiness, hunger):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.happiness = happiness
        self.hunger = hunger


def animal_print(animal):
    if animal.lower() in animals:
        print "%s, the %s, is %s years old. % (animal.name, animal, animal.age)


pig = Animal("Joe", 12, 7, 6)
fox = Animal("Fred", 4, 4, 6),
cow = Animal("Bessy", 9, 6, 3),
horse = Animal("Sally", 7, 8, 8),

animals = ["pig", "fox", "cow", "horse"]


animal_print(raw_input("Which animal would you like to see: "))
```

The basics of this code are that the user will input an animal from the animals list and then I'd like it to return the member attributes. If I change my code to the below it works but ideally I'd like just one print statement for all the class instances whereas the below would require an individual print statement for each instance:

```
def animal_print(animal):
    if animal.lower() in animals:
        print "%s, the %s, is %s years old % (pig.name, animal, pig.age)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `str` `'pig'` is not the same as the instance of `Animal`, stored in the variable `pig`.

`raw_input` returns a `str`. So in the `animal_print` function, `animal` is a `str`. The `str` has no `name` attribute, so `animal.name` will raise an `AttributeError`.

There are at least three ways to fix the code: Use a "whitelist" dict, lookup the value in the `globals()` dict, or use `eval`. Of these three, using a whitelist is the safest, since global lookups and eval should not be allowed on arbitrary user input. One can leak private information, and the other could allow a malicious user to run arbitrary code.

So use a whitelist:

```
animap = {'pig': pig,
          'fox': fox}
anistr = raw_input(...)   # str
animal = animap[anistr]   # Animal instance
```

---

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, happiness, hunger):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.happiness = happiness
        self.hunger = hunger


def animal_print(anistr):
    animal = animap.get(anistr.lower())
    if animal is not None:
        print "%s, the %s, is %s years old." % (animal.name, anistr, animal.age)


pig = Animal("Joe", 12, 7, 6)
fox = Animal("Fred", 4, 4, 6)
cow = Animal("Bessy", 9, 6, 3)
horse = Animal("Sally", 7, 8, 8)

animap = {'pig': pig,
          'fox': fox,
          'cow': cow,
          'horse': horse}

anistr = raw_input("Which animal would you like to see: ")

animal_print(anistr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand what your saying and had kind of figured that's why it wasn't working, Is there any work around to this problem of having the user select a class instance? The raw_input is not essential but I do need the user to be able to select the animal

Comment: Works like a charm, going to have a play around with my code see if I can tidy it up a touch. Thanks again

Comment: You can replace `if anistr.lower() in animap:` with `if animal:` combined with `animal = animap.get(anistr.lower())`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off using a dictionary as a container for your animal instances. The key can be the animal name as a string and the value would be the `Animal` instance. Then your `animal_print()` function can deal only with printing the animal attributes.

```
def animal_print(animal):
    print "%s, the %s, is %s years old." % (animal.name, animal, animal.age)

animals = {
    'pig': Animal("Joe", 12, 7, 6),
    'fox': Animal("Fred", 4, 4, 6),
    'cow': Animal("Bessy", 9, 6, 3),
    'horse': Animal("Sally", 7, 8, 8),
}

user_animal = raw_input("Which animal would you like to see: ")
try:
    animal_print(animals[user_animal.lower()])
except KeyError:
    print "I no nothing about animal %s." % user_animal
```